# Make Dockerfile VOLUME behave like docker-compose volumes

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to setup a `Dockerfile` to mount my host directory to my specified docker container directory (so code changes will be reflected immediately). When I run `docker run -p 3000:3000 -d -v ~/Projects/test:/app test` the files are mounted and everything works fine. However, once I close the container, the file changes don't stay within the container like the changes would if I were running `volumes` from a `docker-compose` file.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:onbuild
EXPOSE 3000
RUN mkdir /app
VOLUME ./:/app/
WORKDIR /app/
RUN npm install -g nodemon
CMD nodemon server.js
```

Here is a working docker-compose.yml:

```
test:
  build: ./
  volumes:
    - ./:/app/
  working_dir: /app/
  command: npm start 
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
```

Answer (score 5):

The `VOLUME` command in Dockerfile has a slightly different meaning:

1. you **cannot** define mounted volumes within a Dockerfile
2. it's only used for specifying inter-container volumes

So in your Dockerfile, `VOLUME ./:/app/` must be changed to `VOLUME /app/`. Your `docker-compose` definition will tell docker to mount local dir `.` to `/app` in the container.

---

The `-v` option and the `volumes` tag in `docker-compose` work the same way. The host directory is mounted to a container directory. Any file which was present in the image in the container directory will be replaced by the files from the host directory.